# Draw an arrow on scatterplot subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw an arrow on the scatterplot. I thought that it would not be hard after [seeing the example here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/arrow_simple_demo.html) and all I need to do is to add the line to my scatterplot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.random.normal(0, 15, 5000), np.random.normal(0, 6, 5000)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
# fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1).scatter(x, y) Some subplot
fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2).scatter(x, y)

fig.arrow(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.1, fc='k', ec='k')
plt.show()
```

But I get `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'arrow'`. Which suggests me that I am chaining arrow to a wrong place. So where should I add it and why?

Comment: in that example `ax` is an `Axes` instance, in your code `fig` is a `Figure` instance.

Comment: You probably want to use `ax.annotate` http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrow()` is a method of `Axes` object, so you'll have to split your one-line `scatter()` call:

```
# instead of
# fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1).scatter(x, y) Some subplot
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.arrow(0, 0, 40, 20, head_width=3, head_length=6, fc='k', ec='k')
```

Also note that this call uses axes-based coordinates.